# Memory Tables in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have been trying to fully understand how the memory works in a program that I write.  I do not have any specific code just generally to get a better understanding of the memory address and contents.  Does anyone know of a way that I can step through a given program and view the memory line by line?

for example:

```
int main(){
    int x;
    x = 5;
    }
```

After line 1 the table would look like this:

Address     |     Contents     |      Variable

AB68 9034    |  FF847392(Garbage) | x

After line 2 the table would look like this:

AB68 9034    |  5 | x

I want to look at code more complicated than this sample and I could write a function to print the memory after each part of the code if there is not.  I am just curious if there is something built in that would do this automatically?

Comment: Most debuggers let you do this. I haven't used Codeblocks. Visual Studio has a good debugger.